# Mobile Safari disables ajax function in iOS 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a mobile app running on jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap, and in iOS 5-only my ajax callback stops firing after a while. I'm using jQuery's `$.ajax` function, and here are some of the error messages I've got:

- textStatus = parsererror
- errorThrown = undefined was not called

In the second error above 'undefined' is my callback function. My question is, does Mobile Safari disable functions after a while if too many errors are thrown?

My guess as to what's occurring is that when a mobile device's connection is too slow, the JSON file I'm grabbing (214K) makes the AJAX call last too long (> 10s?), and Mobile Safari cancels the AJAX call. Then, after X number of cancelled AJAX calls, it seems like Mobile Safari disables the callback function completely.

Anyone else with similar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I use $.ajax often and have not experienced this problem.  I suggest setting timeout to 50000 for a slow connection.  To see the error, somewhere in your html add:

```
 <div id='text1'>No Error yet...</div>
```

and timeout parameter would be added similar to:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "yourpage.html",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout:5000,
    success: function(data){ 
        //something with the data
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $("#text1").text("Comet Timeout ERROR: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
    },
});
```